# How to use Entitiy Framework in a load balanced environment

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have an application based on a code first Entity Framework approach. To update the database I use EF migrations.

Whenever I update the database I also need to update the code and vice versa, otherwise I get a version mismatch.

I am wondering, would it be possible to use Entity Framework in a load balanced environment?

As I see it, the database would need to be updated first, and then gradually each server in the pool, to achieve 0 downtime.

But as mentioned before, the database version mismatch, would cause a problem.

Is there a possibility to disable database checksumming during the database update process?

Comment: Is your DB on the same server as your IIS sites? Or do you have many IIS  sites and one DB server ?

Comment: @Seany84 the db is not on the same server. In case of load balancing many IIS sites and one DB server